# plist does not have NSCameraUsageDescription key how to handle on reviewed app on iTunes connect

Tags: xcode, camera, app-store-connect, plist, ipa

I have uploaded IPA on iTunesConnect and it is reviewed and status is pending developer release.But now during testing it is found that app is crashing on opening camera giving issue The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
Could it be handled now if i do not upload new IPA ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plist can only be changed by uploading a new build on iTunesconnect

Answer (score 0):

No. You need upload new build to fix the issue.

Reject the build and then update the plist and fix the issue. Upload and submit it for review. There is no other option available.